# Ruby on Rails Paperclip Image dimention validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Please help me to make validation for maximum width and height of image.
I have tried like this.

```
validates :picture, dimensions: { width: 612, height: 792 }
```

But I got Unknown validator: 'DimensionsValidator' message.

Kind Regards.

Comment: paper clip does not have dimension validator you will need to add a gem

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have added `gem 'paperclip-dimension-validator'` to your Gemfile